# getRange of null error on code that previously worked

Tags: arrays, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, null

I searched the other instances of people reporting a "getRange" of null error, but none of them solved my issue. I had a form built in Google Sheets, and the code worked perfectly this morning until I made an inadvertent edit, tried to undo the change, but nonetheless I must have done something because the script stopped working.

The script is meant to:

1. Allow a user to create a record by inputing information using code 1000 on the Form sheet, and to save such information to the Data sheet
2. Display a record's information from the Data sheet on the Form sheet when the user enters a code greater than 1000 (a record locator ID)
3. Permit the user to update and save information for the record displayed
4. Reset the form to blank when either the new record is created, or the existing record has been updated.

It worked perfectly this morning, then kaput. I've been trying to debug unsuccessfully for hours, and here are error messages by function:

submitData

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 98, file
> "Code")

getMember

> Exception: Range not found (line 249, file "Code")

onEdit

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getActiveCell' of null (line 378,
> file "Code")

I've been through every line of code, and I am stuck. I humbly request another pair of eyes to help me fix it. Below is the code, and [here is a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nyjGjCn8dKqeytaikQcIflPVBr7EzXnQ9qUITR7R4H8/edit?usp=sharing) to a copy of the form and data table I created with a sample row of data. Please ignore the data validation errors since I deleted proprietary information to create this copy, and please let me know if you have any questions. Thank you.

```
'''
//array for setValue on Data Centre and getValue by column from database
var cellId = ["J3","A"];
var cellPhoto = ["J32","B"];

//Location
var cellStreetAddress = ["D7","C"];
var cellCity = ["D8","D"];
var cellState = ["D9","E"]; 
var cellZip = ["D10","F"]; 
var cellCounty = ["D11","G"];

//Program data
var cellfiftyfive = ["H7","H"];
var cellIL = ["H8","I"];
var cellAL = ["H9","J"];
var cellMC = ["H10","K"];
var cellBeds = ["H12","L"];

//Property Summary
var cellPhase = ["K7","M"];
var cellLand = ["K8","N"];
var cellBuildable = ["K9","O"];
var cellPrice = ["K10","P"];
var cellGrade = ["K11","Q"];
var cellSource = ["K12","R"];
var cellClassification = ["K13","S"];

//Description
var cellSiteDescription = ["D16","T"];
var cellProjDescription = ["D21","U"];

//Site Information
var cellSiteVisit = ["L16","V"];
var cellTeamsLink = ["K17","W"];
var cellGoogleMap = ["K18","X"];

//Zoning
var cellZoningClass = ["K21","Y"];
var cellZoningDesc = ["K22","Z"];
var cellEntitlements = ["K23","AA"];

//Construction
var cellParkingType = ["K26","AB"];
var cellConstType = ["K27","AC"];
var cellUnitSizeRange = ["K28","AD"];
var cellTotalSqFt = ["K29","AE"];

//Financial
var cellTotalCost = ["D32","AF"];
var cellTotalCostDoor = ["D33","AG"];
var cellTotalCostSF = ["D34","AH"];
var cellTotalDebt = ["D35","AI"];
var cellTotalEquity = ["D36","AJ"];
var cellFDGEquity = ["D37","AK"];
var cellCapitalStructure = ["D38","AL"];

//EARLY
var cellDateProcessed = ["H42","AM"];
var cellMarketStudyLink = ["H43","AN"];

//Site Photo
var cellPhotoLibrary = ["K43","AO"];

//Stakeholders
var cellCoDev = ["D46","AP"];
var cellFeeDev = ["D47","AQ"];
var cellOperator = ["D48","AR"];
var cellPartner = ["D49","AS"];
var cellArchitect = ["D50","AT"];
var cellEngineer = ["D51","AU"];
var cellContractor = ["D52","AV"];
var cellBroker = ["D53","AW"];

//Schedule
var cellRezoning = ["H46","AX"];
var cellSitePlan = ["H48","AY"];
var cellPlanPermit = ["H49","AZ"];
var cellClosing = ["H50","BA"];
var cellExtensions = ["H51","BB"];
var cellTimeToClose = ["H52","BC"];
var cellEstConstStart = ["H54","BD"];
var cellEstConstLength = ["H55","BE"];
var cellEstConstFinish = ["H56","BF"];

//Additional Notes
var cellNotes = ["J46","BG"];
var cellDropped = ["J55","BH"];

//Date Stamps
var cellInputDate = ["L3","BI"];//var cellInputDate = ["D23","K"];
var cellUpdateDate = ["L4","BJ"];//var cellUpdateDate = ["H23","L"];

function submitData() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
 var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); 
 var lastrow = datasheet.getLastRow();
 var myId = formSS.getRange(cellId[0]).getValue();
 var maxId = findMaxId(datasheet.getRange("A2:" + "A" + lastrow).getValues());
 var nextId = increaseId(maxId);

  var lastRowId = datasheet.getRange(lastrow,1,1,1).getValue();
  var nextId = increaseId(lastRowId);
  var myId = formSS.getRange(cellId[0]).getValue();
  var now = new Date();
  
  //Location
  var my_StreetAddress = formSS.getRange(cellStreetAddress[0]).getValue(); 
  var my_City = formSS.getRange(cellCity[0]).getValue();
  var my_State = formSS.getRange(cellState[0]).getValue(); 
  var my_Zip = formSS.getRange(cellZip[0]).getValue(); 
  var my_County = formSS.getRange(cellCounty[0]).getValue();
  
  //Program
  var my_fiftyfive = formSS.getRange(cellfiftyfive[0]).getValue();
  var my_IL = formSS.getRange(cellIL[0]).getValue();
  var my_AL = formSS.getRange(cellAL[0]).getValue();
  var my_MC = formSS.getRange(cellMC[0]).getValue();
  var my_Beds = formSS.getRange(cellBeds[0]).getValue();
  
  //Property Summary
  var my_Phase = formSS.getRange(cellPhase[0]).getValue();
  var my_Land = formSS.getRange(cellLand[0]).getValue();
  var my_Buildable = formSS.getRange(cellBuildable[0]).getValue();
  var my_Price = formSS.getRange(cellPrice[0]).getValue();
  var my_Grade = formSS.getRange(cellGrade[0]).getValue();
  var my_Source = formSS.getRange(cellSource[0]).getValue();
  var my_Classification = formSS.getRange(cellClassification[0]).getValue(); 
  
  //Description
  var my_SiteDescription = formSS.getRange(cellSiteDescription[0]).getValue();
  var my_ProjDescription = formSS.getRange(cellProjDescription[0]).getValue();
  
  //Site Information
  var my_SiteVisit = formSS.getRange(cellSiteVisit[0]).getValue();
  var my_TeamsLink = formSS.getRange(cellTeamsLink[0]).getValue();
  var my_GoogleMap = formSS.getRange(cellGoogleMap[0]).getValue();
  
  //Zoning
  var my_ZoningClass = formSS.getRange(cellZoningClass[0]).getValue();
  var my_ZoningDesc = formSS.getRange(cellZoningDesc[0]).getValue();
  var my_Entitlements = formSS.getRange(cellEntitlements[0]).getValue();
  
  //Construction
  var my_ParkingType = formSS.getRange(cellParkingType[0]).getValue();
  var my_ConstType = formSS.getRange(cellConstType[0]).getValue();
  var my_UnitSizeRange = formSS.getRange(cellUnitSizeRange[0]).getValue();
  var my_TotalSqFt = formSS.getRange(cellTotalSqFt[0]).getValue();
  
  //Financial
  var my_TotalCost = formSS.getRange(cellTotalCost[0]).getValue();
  var my_TotalCostDoor = formSS.getRange(cellTotalCostDoor[0]).getValue();
  var my_TotalCostSF = formSS.getRange(cellTotalCostSF[0]).getValue();
  var my_TotalDebt = formSS.getRange(cellTotalDebt[0]).getValue();
  var my_TotalEquity = formSS.getRange(cellTotalEquity[0]).getValue();  
  var my_FDGEquity = formSS.getRange(cellTotalEquity[0]).getValue();
  var my_CapitalStructure = formSS.getRange(cellCapitalStructure[0]).getValue();
  
  //EARLY
  var my_DateProcessed = formSS.getRange(cellDateProcessed[0]).getValue()
  var my_MarketStudyLink = formSS.getRange(cellMarketStudyLink[0]).getValue()
  
  //Site Photo
  var my_Photo = formSS.getRange(cellPhoto[0]).getValue();
  var my_PhotoLibrary = formSS.getRange(cellPhotoLibrary[0]).getValue();
  
  //Stakeholders
  var my_CoDev = formSS.getRange(cellCoDev[0]).getValue();
  var my_FeeDev = formSS.getRange(cellFeeDev[0]).getValue();
  var my_Operator = formSS.getRange(cellOperator[0]).getValue();
  var my_Partner = formSS.getRange(cellPartner[0]).getValue();
  var my_Architect = formSS.getRange(cellArchitect[0]).getValue();
  var my_Engineer = formSS.getRange(cellEngineer[0]).getValue();
  var my_Contractor = formSS.getRange(cellContractor[0]).getValue();
  var my_Broker = formSS.getRange(cellBroker[0]).getValue();
  
  //Schedule
  var my_Rezoning = formSS.getRange(cellRezoning[0]).getValue();
  var my_SitePlan = formSS.getRange(cellSitePlan[0]).getValue();
  var my_PlanPermit = formSS.getRange(cellPlanPermit[0]).getValue();
  var my_Closing = formSS.getRange(cellClosing[0]).getValue();
  var my_Extensions = formSS.getRange(cellExtensions[0]).getValue();
  var my_TimeToClose = formSS.getRange(cellTimeToClose[0]).getValue();
  var my_EstConstStart = formSS.getRange(cellEstConstStart[0]).getValue();
  var my_EstConstLength = formSS.getRange(cellEstConstLength[0]).getValue();
  var my_EstConstFinish = formSS.getRange(cellEstConstFinish[0]).getValue();
  
  //Additional Notes
  var my_Notes = formSS.getRange(cellNotes[0]).getValue();
  var my_Dropped = formSS.getRange(cellDropped[0]).getValue();

  
  if (myId == 1000) { //input mode
      var values = [
                 nextId,'',my_StreetAddress,my_City,my_State,my_Zip,my_County,my_fiftyfive,my_IL,my_AL,my_MC,my_Beds,my_Phase,my_Land,my_Buildable,my_Price,my_Grade,
                 my_Source,my_Classification,my_SiteDescription,my_ProjDescription,my_SiteVisit,my_TeamsLink,my_GoogleMap,my_ZoningClass,my_ZoningDesc,my_Entitlements,
                 my_ParkingType,my_ConstType,my_UnitSizeRange,my_TotalSqFt,my_TotalCost,my_TotalCostDoor,my_TotalCostSF,my_TotalDebt,my_TotalEquity,my_FDGEquity,my_CapitalStructure,
                 my_DateProcessed,my_MarketStudyLink,my_PhotoLibrary,my_CoDev,my_FeeDev,my_Operator,my_Partner,my_Architect,my_Engineer,
                 my_Contractor,my_Broker,my_Rezoning,my_SitePlan,my_PlanPermit,my_Closing,my_Extensions,my_TimeToClose,
                 my_EstConstStart,my_EstConstLength,my_EstConstFinish,my_Notes,my_Dropped,now
                 ];
       datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 61).setValues(values); 
       clear_screen();
  } else { //update mode
          var rowIndex = findInRow(myId);
  var rangesToSetValues = [cellStreetAddress[1], cellCity[1], cellState[1], cellZip[1], cellCounty[1], cellfiftyfive[1], cellIL[1],
                     cellAL[1], cellMC[1], cellBeds[1], cellPhase[1], cellLand[1], cellBuildable[1],
                     cellPrice[1], cellGrade[1], cellSource[1], cellClassification[1], cellSiteDescription[1], cellProjDescription[1],
                     cellSiteVisit[1], cellTeamsLink[1], cellGoogleMap[1], cellZoningClass[1], cellZoningDesc[1], cellEntitlements[1],
                     cellParkingType[1], cellConstType[1], cellUnitSizeRange[1], cellTotalSqFt[1],cellTotalCost[1], cellTotalCostDoor[1], cellTotalCostSF[1],
                     cellTotalDebt[1], cellTotalEquity[1], cellFDGEquity[1], cellCapitalStructure[1], cellDateProcessed[1], cellMarketStudyLink[1], cellPhotoLibrary[1],
                     cellCoDev[1], cellFeeDev[1], cellOperator[1], cellPartner[1], cellArchitect[1], cellEngineer[1],
                     cellContractor[1], cellBroker[1], cellRezoning[1], cellSitePlan[1], cellPlanPermit[1], cellClosing[1],
                     cellExtensions[1], cellTimeToClose[1], cellEstConstStart[1], cellEstConstLength[1], cellEstConstFinish[1], cellNotes[1],cellDropped[1]]; 
    var values = [
                 my_StreetAddress,my_City,my_State,my_Zip,my_County,my_fiftyfive,my_IL,my_AL,my_MC,my_Beds,my_Phase,my_Land,my_Buildable,my_Price,my_Grade,
                 my_Source,my_Classification,my_SiteDescription,my_ProjDescription,my_SiteVisit,my_TeamsLink,my_GoogleMap,my_ZoningClass,my_ZoningDesc,my_Entitlements,
                 my_ParkingType,my_ConstType,my_UnitSizeRange,my_TotalSqFt,my_TotalCost,my_TotalCostDoor,my_TotalCostSF,my_TotalDebt,my_TotalEquity,my_FDGEquity,my_CapitalStructure,
                 my_DateProcessed,my_MarketStudyLink,my_PhotoLibrary,my_CoDev,my_FeeDev,my_Operator,my_Partner,my_Architect,my_Engineer,
                 my_Contractor,my_Broker,my_Rezoning,my_SitePlan,my_PlanPermit,my_Closing,my_Extensions,my_TimeToClose,my_EstConstStart,my_EstConstLength,
                 my_EstConstFinish,my_Notes,my_Dropped 
                ];
    for (var i=0; i<rangesToSetValues.length; i++) {
      datasheet.getRange(rangesToSetValues[i]+rowIndex).setValue(values[i]);
     }
    //set lastupdateDate value
    datasheet.getRange(cellUpdateDate[1]+rowIndex).setValue(now);
    getMember(myId);
  }
}

function getMember(id) {
  var sheetData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form');
  var rangesToSetValues = [cellStreetAddress[0], cellCity[0], cellState[0], cellZip[0], cellCounty[0], cellfiftyfive[0], cellIL[0],
                     cellAL[0], cellMC[0], cellBeds[0], cellPhase[0], cellLand[0], cellBuildable[0],
                     cellPrice[0], cellGrade[0], cellSource[0], cellClassification[0], cellSiteDescription[0], cellProjDescription[0],
                     cellSiteVisit[0], cellTeamsLink[0], cellGoogleMap[0], cellZoningClass[0], cellZoningDesc[0], cellEntitlements[0],
                     cellParkingType[0], cellConstType[0], cellUnitSizeRange[0], cellTotalSqFt[0], cellTotalCost[0], cellTotalCostDoor[0], cellTotalCostSF[0],
                     cellTotalDebt[0], cellTotalEquity[0], cellFDGEquity[0], cellCapitalStructure[0], cellDateProcessed[0], cellMarketStudyLink[0], cellPhotoLibrary[0],
                     cellCoDev[0], cellFeeDev[0], cellOperator[0], cellPartner[0], cellArchitect[0], cellEngineer[0],
                     cellContractor[0], cellBroker[0], cellRezoning[0], cellSitePlan[0], cellPlanPermit[0], cellClosing[0],
                     cellExtensions[0], cellTimeToClose[0], cellEstConstStart[0], cellEstConstLength[0], cellEstConstFinish[0], cellNotes[0], cellDropped[0],
                     cellInputDate[0], cellUpdateDate[0]]; 
  var rowIndex = findInRow(id);
  var sheetDatabase = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data'); 

    var values = [
                 //Location
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellStreetAddress[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellCity[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellState[1]+rowIndex).getValue(), 
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellZip[1]+rowIndex).getValue(), 
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellCounty[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 //Program data
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellfiftyfive[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellIL[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellAL[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellMC[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellBeds[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 
                 //Property Summary
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellPhase[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellLand[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellBuildable[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellPrice[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellGrade[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellSource[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellClassification[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 
                 //Description
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellSiteDescription[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellProjDescription[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 
                 //Site Information
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellSiteVisit[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellTeamsLink[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellGoogleMap[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 
                 //Zoning
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellZoningClass[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),                 
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellZoningDesc[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellEntitlements[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 
                 //Construction
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellParkingType[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellConstType[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellUnitSizeRange[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellTotalSqFt[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 
                 //Financial
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellTotalCost[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellTotalCostDoor[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellTotalCostSF[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellTotalDebt[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),                 
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellTotalEquity[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellFDGEquity[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellCapitalStructure[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 
                 //EARLY
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellDateProcessed[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellMarketStudyLink[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),

                 //Site Photo
                 //sheetDatabase.getRange(cellPhoto[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellPhotoLibrary[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
        
                 //Stakeholders
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellCoDev[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellFeeDev[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),       
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellOperator[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellPartner[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellArchitect[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellEngineer[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellContractor[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),       
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellBroker[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 
                 //Schedule
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellRezoning[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellSitePlan[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellPlanPermit[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),       
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellClosing[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellExtensions[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellTimeToClose[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellEstConstStart[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),       
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellEstConstLength[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),       
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellEstConstFinish[1]+rowIndex).getValue(), 
                 
                 //Additional Notes
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellNotes[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellDropped[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 
                 //Data Stamps
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellInputDate[1]+rowIndex).getValue(),
                 sheetDatabase.getRange(cellUpdateDate[1]+rowIndex).getValue()
                
                ];
    for (var i=0; i<rangesToSetValues.length; i++) {
      sheetData.getRange(rangesToSetValues[i]).setValue(values[i]);
  }
}

function findInRow(id) {
  var sheetDatabase = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data');
  var rows  = sheetDatabase.getRange("A2:A").getValues(); 

  for (var r=0; r<rows.length; r++) {
    if ( rows[r][0] === id ) {
      return r+2;
    }
  }

  return -1;

}

function increaseId(id) {
  if(id>0) {
    var returnId;
    returnId = id + 1;
    return returnId;
  }
}

function findMaxId(myvalues){
  return Math.max.apply(null, myvalues);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  //initialization
  /*var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form'); //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Reception');
  sheet.getRange(cellId[0]).setValue(1000);
  clear_screen();*/
}

function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.setActiveSelection(e.range.offset(2, 0));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form'); 
  var rangeRowId = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var rangeColId = sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  //Browser.msgBox("Row Id: " + rangeRowId + " Column Id: " + rangeColId );
  if(rangeRowId == 3 && rangeColId == 10) {
    var myId = sheet.getRange(cellId[0]).getValue();
    lookUpId(myId);
  }

}

function clear_screen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form'); 
  var rangesToClear = [cellStreetAddress[0], cellCity[0], cellState[0], cellZip[0], cellCounty[0], cellfiftyfive[0], cellIL[0],
                     cellAL[0], cellMC[0], cellBeds[0], cellPhase[0], cellLand[0], cellBuildable[0],
                     cellPrice[0], cellGrade[0], cellSource[0], cellClassification[0], cellSiteDescription[0], cellProjDescription[0],
                     cellSiteVisit[0], cellTeamsLink[0], cellGoogleMap[0], cellZoningClass[0], cellZoningDesc[0], cellEntitlements[0],
                     cellParkingType[0], cellConstType[0], cellUnitSizeRange[0], cellTotalSqFt[0], cellTotalCost[0], cellTotalCostDoor[0], cellTotalCostSF[0],
                     cellTotalDebt[0], cellTotalEquity[0], cellFDGEquity[0], cellCapitalStructure[0], cellDateProcessed[0], cellMarketStudyLink[0], cellPhotoLibrary[0], cellCoDev[0],
                     cellFeeDev[0], cellOperator[0], cellPartner[0], cellArchitect[0], cellEngineer[0], cellContractor[0], cellBroker[0], cellRezoning[0], 
                     cellSitePlan[0], cellPlanPermit[0], cellClosing[0], cellExtensions[0], cellTimeToClose[0], cellEstConstStart[0], cellEstConstLength[0], 
                     cellEstConstFinish[0], cellNotes[0], cellDropped[0], cellInputDate[0], cellUpdateDate[0]]; 
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
  }
  var myCellStreetAddress = sheet.getRange(cellStreetAddress[0]);
  myCellStreetAddress.activateAsCurrentCell();
}

function lookUpId(id) {
  if (id==1000) { //Data Centre mode
    clear_screen();
  }
  if (id>1000) { //lookup mode
    getMember(id);
  }
}

'''
```

Comment: Could you please indicate the lines of code that don't work and also what is the expected output? Your question needs more focus on the part of the code that does not work. Try to Logger.log the object you want to getRange() and returns error.

Comment: @MariosKaramanis, thanks for the feedback. I added the purpose of the script, form and data sheet to my original question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you please check the history of the file to see all the changes that were made ? You can see the historical changes for both the script and the file itself. I am feeling that you made a unintentional change in the spreadsheet file itself.

Comment: @MariosKaramanis All hail! You sir, are my savior! You were correct. Problem solved. Thank you for the second set of eyes and clear head.